# How do I get a Security Token? ... Chatter Free Salesforce User - PE w/ API

Tags: c#, salesforce, salesforce-chatter

Story: As the developer, I want to get a Salesforce security token for a Chatter Free profile user so that my application can pull Chatter Feed.

I’m developing a VS 2010 C# internal application to pull data from Chatter via Salesforce’s API.  Sample application I wrote using my Salesforce developers edition Chatter Free account functions just fine.  However, I’m unable to get a security token for the Chatter Free user account set up through my company.  Company has PE with API bundled in.  I’ve determined that some users in the company are able to request a security token and others are not .. yet I don’t see a pattern among the different user accounts.
My company does not want to provide our IPs to Salesforce.

How do I get a security token in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: A regular paid user account was set up specifically for our internal application's usage. This allowed me to get the needed security token and pull the chatter data feed into my custom applicaiton. Our company didn't have to change subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to request security token for Chatter Free users.  You have to access the Salesforce web UI to do it (so even API-only standard users can't do it either).  The only workaround is to white list IP, but apparently you're unable to do...

Comment: Do you mean that all Chatter Free users cannot request security tokens or just the ones tied into PE??    Sample application I wrote using my Salesforce developers edition Chatter Free account functions just fine and that requires a security token.

Comment: @CodeHawk how did you do that?

Comment: @PerlDev Once the paid user account is created the user management area has an option to email the security token. Does that help?